# How to characterize the images of disk-algebra functions?

Tags: gn.general-topology, cv.complex-variables

It is well known that the continuous images  $f:\mathbf D\to \mathbb C$ of the closed unit disk $\mathbf D$ are exactly the non-void
compact, connected,  locally path connected  sets in $\mathbb C$.
In the Oberwolfach report 6 (2008) it was  asked on page 344 for a geometric/topological characterization of those planar compacta which are images of a disk-algebra function. This problem still seems to be unsolved.    Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Is the Oberwolfach report that you cite available online? If yes, please give a link.

Comment: Just type Oberwolfach report 6 (2008) at the google search.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko You can also use https://www.mfo.de/document/0807a/OWR_2008_06.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=f(\overline{D})$, where $f$ is analytic in $D$, continuous in $\overline{D}$, and non-constant. Then $E$ has these properties:

a) Interior of $E$ is a bounded region (connected and not empty),

b) $E$ is the closure of its interior,

c) $E$ is locally path connected.

To prove a) let $w_i=f(z_i), i\in\{1,2\}$ be two interior points of $E$, $z_i\in \overline{D}$.
Let $\gamma$ be a curve in $\overline D$ which belongs to $D$ except possibly
its endpoints, and $\gamma$ connects $z_1,z_2$. The image of $\gamma$ connects
$w_1,w_2$and completely belongs to the interior of $E$: all points except the
endpoints, because $f$ is open in $D$ and endpoints by assumption.

To prove b), let $w_0\in E$. Then $w_0=f(z_0), z_0\in\overline{D}$, and there is a sequence $z_j\to z_0,\; z_j\in D, j\geq 1$. The points $w_j=f(z_j)$ are
in the interior of $E$ and $f(w_j)\to w_0$.

c) is the property of all continuous functions as stated in the question.

Now I suppose that a),b,c) are sufficient. Let $\Omega$ be the interior of $E$.
There is a system of cuts $I_j$ such that removing these cuts will make $\Omega$ simply connected.
Then the conformal map $f:D\to\Omega\backslash\cup I_j$ is the required function. The problem is how to show rigorously that such cuts exist, so that the resulting region has locally connected boundary.

Remark. I suppose that the natural method to make cuts is to condsider
the universal cover of the interior, and take the Dirichlet fundamental region of the associated Fuchsian group. The image of the boundary of this region will give a system of cuts.

Comment: I agree that what I wrote is incomplete. I was answering the last sentence of your question.

Comment: @ray Comments should be posted as comments, and not as answers. -- If your text is too long (i.e. longer than 600 characters), you can post multiple comments. In your case, two comments provide sufficient space.

Comment: Yes. Nice idea. But how to "construct" these cuts if $E$ is, say, a certain Swiss cheese where many disks are removed from the closed unit square $Q$ e.g?
  I see a procedure only for concrete examples.

Comment: Say one removes from $Q$ smaller and smaller  disks $D_j$ (p.w. disjoint) centred at real points $c_j$. Then the cuts cannot be taken as a segment joining $D_j$ with the lower side of $Q$, as the resulting domain would no longer have a locally connected boundary. So one may join  the disks horizontally, excepted two adjacent of them (to get a domain). But what choice is to be made for an abstract/arbitrary set $E$ satisfying a)b)c)?

Comment: @StefanKohl This restriction to 600 characters does not make sense to me.  I splitted it, but what's the difference between  splitting the comment and writing it in a single comment?

Comment: @ray The matter is that comments are comments and answers are answers. The distinction is by content rather than by length.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko The image with respect to which map you had in mind?

Comment: @ray: under the inverse Riemann map of the unit disk onto $\Omega\backslash\cup I_j$, as written in my answer.